# Email Sending when task is created

Tags: tasks, vf-email-template

I have a requirement to send out emails when tasks are assigned to the assigned user. These tasks are specific for cases, meaning tasks are created only for cases. The template has the subject line that involves case fields viz: CaseNumber while the body has task related fields.
I was trying to have vf email template to achieve this. However I can't make  reference to caseNumber using `relatedTo.whatId.caseNumber` where relatedTo is Task. What is the way forward if workflow is to be used for this requirement.

The initial template looks something like this :

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Subject:Task Notification - Action Required on {!relatedTo.whatId.CaseNumber}" recipientType="Contact"  relatedToType="Task">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
Task with the following subject has been assigned to you.
Subject : {!relatedTo.Subject}


</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Have you tried using '{!relatedTo.CaseNumber}'?

Comment: Yes. Gives out this error . 'Error: Invalid field CaseNumber for SObject Task'

Comment: Actually, the issue here is that you may be accessing any object for this email template i.e whatId is polymorphic. I believe you will need to implement a controller to handle this case.